# HDMI second monitor stopped working

Tags: 16.10

I have an LG monitor and my laptop was connected to it via HDMI with sound working and all, then I changed the sound back to the internal speakers and when I tried to change it again to HDMI the monitor just stopped working, it only works with VGA now.

xrandr does not even recognize my monitor when connected with HDMI.

My laptop does work with other monitors/TVs/projectors through HDMI (and I can change the sound settings as much as I want).

Any ideas how to fix this? (please request any info/command output you need)

Comment: Does it work on your TV with the same cable?

Comment: Yes. (and I have to write more characters to be able to comment)

Comment: Does the monitor work on any other computer? (I'm thinking its HDMI port is bust)

Comment: Eduardo you describe troubleshooting results that are unclear.  Laptop works connected to other monitors via HDMI using the same cable as the one used in the LG monitor test, correct?  If so, this eliminates everything except the LG monitor itself.  So....  does the LG monitor, using the known good HDMI cable, work on anything else?  I'm guessing it doesn't which means a bad monitor.  This is rather common, unfortunately, even on new monitors.  There's a VERY outside chance the problem could be due to some driver issue so checking that might be wise.

Comment: Ok, I'll test the monitor with some other computer (which I can't right now) and then give some feedback.

Answer (score 3):

Given the limited information to date this is the closest answer I could find to your problems: [[SOLVED] Xrandr it doesn't detect HDMI output](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=204800).

In a nut shell you may need to:

- Implement Intel early microcode updates
- Utilize a command something like: `xrandr --output LVDS-1-0 --auto --rotate normal --pos 0x0 --output HDMI-0 --auto --rotate normal  --left-of LVDS-1-0 --output VGA-0 --right-of LVDS-1-0`

Please try appropriate solutions in the link. Then report back success or how your system is different then we can work from there.